# How can we pass dictionary object in Django url?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am new to the Django framework, so I would like to know how I can pass a dictionary object as a parameter to a Django URL. How would I retrieve it as a dictionary object in my view?

Answer (score 1):

You can url encode the dict as below. You can get them in view through view parameters by appropriately writing pattern in urls.py, or through `request.GET.get('key1')` in your view (here 'key1' is name of variable to be passed). So basically you will have to reconstruct the dict.

```
import urllib
my_dict = { 'key1': 'abc', 'key2': 100 }
uri = urllib.urlencode(my_dict)
fullurl = your_server_url + "/?" + uri
```

here `your_server_url` is assumed to be your url

Answer (score 0):

What Rohan said will do exactly what you want.

However, since you say you are new to Django I'd suggest you use the included batteries instead. As far as I can tell there is exactly one corner case where you'd want to pass a dictionary in the URL (which is when you are bringing in a user for the first time and want to bring some information with them).

If the above is not your use case, look into [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) instead.

If the you are trying to import information about your users via a URL please remember to validate the stuff you are getting.